# How can I generate LPK file without the GUI of LPK_tool

Tags: activex

I use the lpk_tool.exe to generate the LPK file for my ActiveX control. But it seems that Microsoft have abandoned this technology, I cannot even find the download link on Microsoft Download.

But that's not a problem, I can download it from other website. The problem is now I want generate LPK file without the GUI. I tried to find the API or command line support for LPK tool, but failed to find any. I have also asked the support form Microsoft and they don't provide the API or source code of the LPK tool.

Anyone can help me?